# Binary search for minimal failing value

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a command `cmd`. `cmd 1` succeeds, but `cmd 10000000` fails.

`cmd` will succeed for all n < X, and fail for all n > X.

Is there a tool for doing binary search to find the value X?

Answer (score 2):

`find-first-fail` (https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/blob/master/find-first-fail/find-first-fail) is implemented in `bash`. It can be called as a command:

```
find-first-fail cmd
```

Or can be sourced - in which case `cmd` can be a function:

```
. $(which find-first-fail)
find-first-fail cmd
```

`find-first-fail` first runs `cmd 1`. If that fails it will look for the minimal value where `cmd` succeeds. Else it will look for the minimal value where `cmd` fails.

So it will also find X if `cmd 1` fails, and `cmd 1000000` succeeds.

It does this using binary search: First it doubles the value until the exit code changes, then it does binary search between the last two values.